# In how many ways can I fill a list of lists

Tags: probability, statistics

I have 220 items to fill a list of lists with, where, the outer list consists of 45 inner lists.

Each of the 45 inner lists can have:

1. Maximum of 10 items.
2. Can be empty.

So, the list of lists can have up to a maximum of 450 items, but we only need to fill 220 spots and the rest will be empty.

- The order of the items inside the inner list does not matter.
- An item can only be used once throughout the all 45 lists.
- The order of the inner lists matters. [[3,4], [1,2]] is not equal [[1,2], [3,4]]

**E.g:**

[[1,2],[9,7,55,66,77,99], [], [23,42,51,11], ...]

Comment: An item can only be used once per list, or once throughout all $45$ lists?

Comment: @KevinLong An item can only be used once thoughout all lists

Comment: Does the order of the inner lists matter? e.g. is $[[1, 2], [3, 4]]$ different from $[[3, 4], [1, 2]]$?

Comment: Does every item have to be used at all?

Comment: @MarcusStuhr Yes, [[1,2], [3,4]] is different from [[3,4],[1,2]]

Comment: @KevinLong Yes, all items must be used.

Comment: At least $_{220}C_{10}*_{210}C_{10}*_{200}C_{10}・・・$.